# Easy way to grep for text in one file only in directories containing a second file

Tags: grep

**Background:**
We have a process that is not running correctly.  It is supposed to only run on files with patterns like "AAA*.x12".  However, it is also running on files similar to "BBB*.x12"  Each directory only contains an AAA type type or BBB type file.  While there is an output.log that contains the data I am looking for, it does not contain the name of the file being processed.

**Question:**
I want to grep a string in a filename in a large number of directories.  However, I only want to look at directories that contain a second file matching a specific pattern.

In other words, how can I grep the output.log files only in directories that contain files starting with BBB, and ignore the output.log files in directories that contain files starting with AAA

**Note:** The directory names are sequential numbers and cannot be used to determine which type files they contain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick pseudo code, without trying to make an actual script -- want to make sure I understand the questions. Also, assume well-behaved file names (if necessary, robustify the final script to handle file names with control characters, etc).

```
# get output.log files in directories containing BBB file and search output.log
find /start -name 'BBB*' -type f -print |\
while read f; do echo $(dirname $f)/output.log; done |\
xargs grep search-string
```

Does that get you on the right track?

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i need to do

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm still a little unclear about the nature of the question, this is my punt.

if a directory contains either AAA.x12 *or* BBB.x12, but not both *and* you want to recursively grep *only* files named `output.log` within directories containing `BBB.x12`

`find  -type f -name 'BBB.x12' -printf '%h\n' |  grep -d recurse -sinI string --include="output.log"`

Comment: didn't work for me. I should have included my system type, solaris did not support the 'printf' flag for find;

Comment: @Noah, `find -type f -name 'BBB.x12' -print | xargs ls -d | grep -d recurse -sinI string --include="output.log"`